# Loop in js with CanvasJS chart

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, canvasjs

I have this code (JS + PHP)

```js
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
        { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> }
```

All the lines are equal, except the last, this don't have a ","

I need loop this code, but the for loop don't work, I try this, but don't work:

```js
for(var j = 0; j <= 20; j++)
    { x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> },
{ x: new Date(2012, 1, 1, <?php echo $i - 1; ?>), y: <?php echo $invertir[$i]; $i++; ?> }
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: So you are trying to generate an array with a format that canvasjs can interpret? It seems to me, that you are trying to bruteforce the creation of an array , which doesn't work this way. What are you achieving with this code? I am no Javascrit expert, but for me your code does nothing. You have to push the different elements to a variable, so you don't need to determine if you need a comma or not. Which is your data source? A JSON file? A SQL Table?

Comment: I'm trying repeat a js line, but this for loop don't work. CanvasJS can interpret this line. The source of the array $invertir is a MySQL Database. If I type all the lines, work, but the loop don't work.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, trying to manually force the creation of an array with data is a bad approach. Because you use MySQL, you can try something like that:

```
// Creamos una array vacía

$myDataPoints = array();

// Usa la siguiente variable $conexion...

$conexion = mysqli_connect("tuIP","tuUser","tuPassword","tuDB");

// o adapta la siguiente línea con la variable previamente creada por ti

$rawData = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tablaConDatos");

// Ejecutamos el Loop para cada línea de resultados de la consulta 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rawData))
{

/* Calculamos la fecha. En tu ejemplo, parece que sólo quieres variar la hora
sustrayendo 1 hora a cada número de línea. Este método sólo funciona si tu
tabla de datos tiene menos de 25 líneas */

$fecha = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime($row - 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2012));

// Creamos el objeto... 

$point = array("x" => $fecha , "y" => $row['invertir']);

// ... y lo mandamos al array 

array_push($myDataPoints, $point);

echo 'var myDataPoints = '.json_encode($myDataPoints).';';

}
```

This approach generates an JSON array (myDataPoints) that you can easily use in a normal canvasjs call:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    data: [
                        {
                            dataPoints: myDataPoints
                        }
                    ]
                });
```